# Creating co-autorship graph in neo4j

Tags: xml, neo4j

I have converted a xml file to a cypher query, using the `xml2graph` converter,by Nigel Small. As a result, there were some blank nodes as an inheritance of xml format. The CYPHER  query is this (sorry for the long post):

```
CREATE
(N0),
(N1 {publicationDate:"2007-12-18",
    title:"RECONHECIMENTO E AGRUPAMENTO",`title     language`:"por"}),
(N2),
(N3 {name:"RG"}),
(N4 {name:"SWMS"}),
(N5 {name:"MHLBB"}),
(N6 {name:"RNM"}),
(N7 {publicationDate:"2007-12-18",title:"LOCPN",`title language`:"por"}),
(N8),
(N9 {name:"MFCS"}),
(N10 {name:"DGG"}),
(N11 {name:"GCB"}),
(N12 {name:"CTS"}),
(N13 {name:"JACF"}),
(N14 {name:"MCP"}),
(N15 {name:"RMCA"}),
(N16 {publicationDate:"2007-12-18",
    title:"CCONTEXTOGRAD",`title language`:"por"}),
(N17),
(N18 {name:"JB"}),
(N19 {name:"RH"}),
(N20 {name:"SR"}),
(N21 {name:"SCCP"}),
(N22 {name:"DNFB"}),
(N23 {publicationDate:"2008-04-18",
    title:"GENETICOL",`title language`:"por"}),
(N24),
(N25 {name:"AGDC"}),
(N26 {name:"GAA"}),
(N27 {name:"MN"}),
(N28 {name:"RDL"}),
N0-[R0:record]->N1,
N1-[R1:authors]->N2,
N2-[R2:author]->N3,
N2-[R3:author]->N4,
N2-[R4:author]->N5,
N2-[R5:author]->N6,
N0-[R6:record]->N7,
N7-[R7:authors]->N8,
N8-[R8:author]->N9,
N8-[R9:author]->N10,
N8-[R10:author]->N11,
N8-[R11:author]->N12,
N8-[R12:author]->N13,
N8-[R13:author]->N14,
N8-[R14:author]->N15,
N0-[R15:record]->N16,
N16-[R16:authors]->N17,
N17-[R17:author]->N18,
N17-[R18:author]->N19,
N17-[R19:author]->N20,
N17-[R20:author]->N21,
N17-[R21:author]->N22,
N0-[R22:record]->N23,
N23-[R23:authors]->N24,
N24-[R24:author]->N25,
N24-[R25:author]->N26,
N24-[R26:author]->N27,
N24-[R27:author]->N28
```

=============================

As I tried to create a graph with co-autorship relation, i issued this query:

```
START title=node:node_auto_index('title:*'), author = node:node_auto_index('name:*') 
MATCH a-[:author]->title<-[:author]-b 
CREATE UNIQUE a-[coaut:coautores]-b
```

On neo4j console, but the output shows no additional relation, database was not changed, although syntax is OK. I am wondering that the cause are the blank nodes coming from xml (records, record, authors). Is there any way to solve this? The original file is a large one so that manual correction is infeasible. Should I delete these nodes and their relationships? Obrigado, Thank you!

Comment: try instead of `create unique ...`, `return *` to see if there are any results for the match

Comment: Hi, [Wes Freeman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/683201/wes-freeman), I have considered your suggestion, but there were no changes. I am sure I must get rid of these blank nodes, since the original dataset is a xml one. I consider generating the query string from direct manipulation of the xml file, and so extract relevant data and create the CYPHER string. It is not a straight method, but I think it could work.